# Media recorder reduce output file size

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I record audio file using media recorder
And i want to reduce the output file size or quality
How to Reduce the output file size with low quality?

This is my code

```
private MediaRecorder recorder = null;

int audioformat = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(Preferences.PREF_AUDIO_FORMAT, "1"));
    switch (audioformat) {
    case MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP:
        suffix = ".3gpp";
        break;
    case MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4:
        suffix = ".mpg";
        break;
    case MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR:
        suffix = ".amr";
        break;

    }

     recorder.setAudioSource(audiosource);        recorder.setOutputFormat(audioformat); recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
  recorder.setOutputFile(recording.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: It is related to the sampling rate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354269/sample-rate-in-android-audio-record-class-and-mediarecord-class

Answer (score 0):

[Use `setProfile()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setProfile%28android.media.CamcorderProfile%29), choosing a lower-quality [`CamcorderProfile`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html), such as `QUALITY_LOW`.

Comment: I try this recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW)); but the output file size 0,0 kb

Comment: What is the mistake?